# Update QAbstractItemModel from external data source

Tags: c++, model, qt5, qabstractitemmodel, qmodelindex

I want to use QAbstractItemModel as many times before which will hold a tree structure from an external model. This model can send notifications before deleting a row and after finishing deleting a row. These notofications can happen at any time (within same GUI thread).

QAbstractItemModel has the beginRemoveRows and endRemoveRows which is then connected to the model signals. What I don't understand is how I get the QModelIndex. My underlying data model does not know anything about QAbstractItemModel which is per design because I wan to use that in other places where Qt is inacceptable.

What is the right way to get the QModelIndex when I know what is the index of the element inside the underlying data structure and have access to the parent?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex

Comment: I use that but there is an image in beginRemoveRows where the indices are shown. After removal they do not match my model anymore.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: In your implementation of `QAbstractItemModel` you can assign an id to each item of your underlying model and then use another overload of [createIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex-1) which accepts an id. Then in `data` you could look up the underlying model's element by that id from the index.